# How to processing json data in a column by using python/pyspark?

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks, azure-databricks

Trying to process JSON data in a column on Databricks. Below is the sample data from a table (its a weather device records info)

| JSON_Info |
| --- |
| {"sampleData":"dataDetails: 1 001 2010/01/02 01:09:10 [device_info(1)] Weather=65F Wind Speed(mph)=12 UV Index=0_2 "} |
| {"sampleData":"dataDetails: 2 002 2010/01/02 01:10:03 [device_info(1)] Weather=66F Wind Speed(mph)=13 UV Index=0_2 "} |
| {"sampleData":"dataDetails: 3 003 2010/01/02 01:11:14 [device_info(1)] Weather=67F Wind Speed(mph)=14 UV Index=0_2 "} |
| {"sampleData":"dataDetails: 4 004 2010/01/02 01:12:23 [device_info(1)] Weather=68F Wind Speed(mph)=15 UV Index=0_2 "} |

All the info start with "sampleData" as the key, the value is the long piece info like below:  "dataDetails: 1 001 2010/01/02 01:09:10 [device_info(1)] Weather=65F Wind Speed(mph)=12 UV Index=0_2 ".

Ideally, I would love to get muli info from the value(**dataDetails**) into different columns like below:

| Index | SI | Date | Time | DeviceNumber | WeatherDegree | WindSpeed | UVIndex |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 001 | 2010/01/02 | 01:09:10 | [device_info(1)] | 65F | 12 | 0_2 |
| 2 | 002 | 2010/01/02 | 01:10:03 | [device_info(1)] | 66F | 13 | 0_2 |
| 3 | 003 | 2010/01/02 | 01:11:14 | [device_info(1)] | 67F | 14 | 0_2 |
| 4 | 004 | 2010/01/02 | 01:12:23 | [device_info(1)] | 68F | 15 | 0_2 |

Below are some of my thoughts(but not sure how to approach):

1. once get the info like "**1 001 2010/01/02 01:09:10 [device_info(1)] Weather=65F Wind Speed(mph)=12 UV Index=0_2**", separate the long piece by space to get most of the info (before separate, need to remove the space from "Wind Speed" and  "UV Index" to "WindSpeed" and "UVIndex" .
2. then get the left side of the "=" sign as the column name (if there is an equal sign)

In short, how to use python/pyspark to get muli info of the value inside a JSON data column

Can someone please help?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your column is JSON type already, you can use `from_csv` function with option `sep: ' '` to use blank space as separator

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

(df
    .withColumn('JSON_Info', F.from_json('JSON_Info', 'sampleData string'))
    .select(F.from_csv('JSON_Info.sampleData', 'c1 string, Index string, SI string, Date string, Time string, DeviceNumber string, WeatherDegree string, c8 string, Wind string, c10 string, UVIndex string', {'sep': ' '}).alias('csv'))
    .select('csv.*')
    .drop('c1', 'c8', 'c10')
    .withColumn('WeatherDegree', F.split('Weather', '=')[1])
    .withColumn('Wind', F.split('Wind', '=')[1])
    .withColumn('UVIndex', F.split('UVIndex', '=')[1])
    .show()
)

+-----+---+----------+--------+----------------+-------------+----+-------+
|Index|SI |Date      |Time    |DeviceNumber    |WeatherDegree|Wind|UVIndex|
+-----+---+----------+--------+----------------+-------------+----+-------+
|1    |001|2010/01/02|01:09:10|[device_info(1)]|65F          |12  |0_2    |
|2    |002|2010/01/02|01:10:03|[device_info(1)]|66F          |13  |0_2    |
|3    |003|2010/01/02|01:11:14|[device_info(1)]|67F          |14  |0_2    |
|4    |004|2010/01/02|01:12:23|[device_info(1)]|68F          |15  |0_2    |
+-----+---+----------+--------+----------------+-------------+----+-------+
```

Comment: thanks for the help. I am wondering what's 'data.sampleData', Does the data means the table name or the column name?

Comment: It's the column name, I updated to fit with yours

Comment: thank you. Also, I just realize that the column (JSON_Info)  type its a str type, but in a JSON format. I guess that I need to change the column type to JSON type first, then approach? Please correct me if I m wrong. thank you again

Comment: Sure, I updated my answer to accommodate that. You should have told that in your question though :)

Comment: thank you!!! It's really helpful, let me try in my end...

Comment: one more thing, the code is working. However, I am just wondering "    .withColumn('WeatherDegree', F.split('WeatherDegree', '=')[1])", the original data name is Weather,  but it still work fine with .split.

Comment: You're right! My typo mistake, I updated :)